# Facebook SDK iOS access code issue

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

My Project is to get Facebook Insights data of my Fanpage on my iPhone App.

I started by installing Facebook SDK for iOS to get Access Code & than using SampleLoginSample Sample Program provided with Facebook iOS SDK.

Its working Perfect & giving same response as in Facebook API Explporer for Query

```
[self.textNoteOrLink setText:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]?fields=likes&access_token=%@",appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];
```

but if i am writing below Query its not giving me response as in Facebook Explorer API

QUERY:

```
[self.textNoteOrLink setText:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/insights/page_fans?access_token=%@",appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];
```

RESPONSE:

```
{"data":[

],"paging":{

"previous":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/PAGEID\/insights\/page_fans?access_token=CAA...snip...h2l&since=1378984583&until=1379243783","next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/PAGEID\/insights\/page_fans?access_token=CAA...snip...h2l&since=1379502983&until=1379762183"}}
```

Can anyone help me to get access code with get_insights permission in Facebook iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In `SLAppDelegate.h`

Under the list of `@property`, add:

```
-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI;
```

---

#### In `SLAppDelegate.m`

Under `applicationDidBecomeActive`, add:

```
/*
 * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
 */
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"read_insights",
                            nil];
    
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}
```

And:

```
/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

---

#### In `SLViewController.h`

At the end of `viewDidLoad` , add:

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
```

Comment: Where exactly should i add these lines as its showing error of use of undeclared identifier 'facebook' to line#1 & 3 & error of ARC forbids explicit message send of retain in line#2.

Comment: Can you suggest me way where i can mail or share you the code complete for your reference?

Comment: Complete code shared via:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/35re3glq425bfkv/PWkI4rf21U
Can you please check where i need to add your suggested lines to get read_insights data via Facebook API

Comment: Done everything you recommended but Accesscode didnt get read_insights permission & its still not showing read_insights of my Facebook Fanpage - sharing you code for your view:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kib2b363qwu1adw/5g8K-mKQzQ & Output Window also: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kib2b363qwu1adw/5g8K-mKQzQ
Can you please test it on your Fanpage & share me also code via Dropbox if possible

Comment: I will try again when I get back home.

Comment: Please see if you can get read insights values of your fanpage by the code addition you shared - Waiting & Thanks

Comment: Just want to have simple clean code to get Accesscode with read Insights permission in iOS - Can you please share procedure better if you can recommend rather than this code you can share - i will be really thankful

Comment: I have got cleaner version of Facebook iOS code to get accesscode permission - Can you please update code lines so i can get UserInsights of Fanpage views on TextView: Code link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t9gq48tw3zau2ff/GUVnuK5DY0